# Media Query Not Recognized with Angular 8

Tags: css, angular, components, media-queries

I am working on an Angular 8 project and I am trying to apply a media query in a component :

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024) {
  .content {
    max-width: 65%;
    padding: 30px 20px 0;
  }
}
```

In my index.html, the viewport is set :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

But the media query isn't recognized. When I analyzed the CSS applied, the media query isn't here.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add px or em to '1024'.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .content {
    max-width: 65%;
    padding: 30px 20px 0;
  }
}
```